# Modifying Selected ItemBackground drawable in NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a vertical line on the selected item in my NavigationView. I was trying to set it through the xml setting as so:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_selected_item"
```

But this just applies the drawable to the entire list of menu items.

This is my drawer:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/primary_blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_selected"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_view" />
```

The default behavior (when itemBackground attr isn't set to nav_drawer_selected) current puts a transparent lighter shade over **only the selected** item. When I do set it, it doesn't have that behavior anymore. Is the default itemBackground using a selector? How would I approach this effectively? I just want to have one item use my drawable, if it's selected/currently in view, not apply the whole style to the entire list.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Apparently this has been confirmed as a defect by another user. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176570

They say it's slated for "FutureRelease"... Is there a current workaround? Or am I stuck trying to approach this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, try putting a list view inside the NavigationView and handling clicks yourself.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/primary_blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
     />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/nav_selected_item"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_header_height"
            >
        </ListView>
</NavigationView>
```